# Scope of the 'const' keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to style my header differently, as soon as the vertical offset on the page is more than 200. My function (scrollHeader()) does not seem to work. I understand that the const keyword (const yOffset) is blockscoped, but my code does not work either when I put the const above the function declaration.

I use VSCode. When I hover over the this.yOffset, it says 'any'. Does someone know why my variable is not being used?

```
/* ######################## ACTIVE LINK ######################## */

const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section[id]')

function activeLink() {
    const yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 

    sections.forEach(section => {
        var sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;
        var sectionTop = section.offsetTop - 48; //48 is height of the header
        var sectionId = section.getAttribute('id');

        if (yOffset > sectionTop && yOffset <= sectionTop + sectionHeight) {
            document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.add('active-link');
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.nav__menu a[href*=' + sectionId + ']').classList.remove('active-link');
        }
    })
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", activeLink);

/* ###################### BACKGROUND HEADER ###################### */
                                  
function scrollHeader() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');

    if (this.yOffset >= 200) {
        header.classList.add('scroll-header');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('scroll-header');
    }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHeader);
```

Comment: Are you basically trying to read the current `window.pageYOffset` inside `scrollHeader`? Then simply read from that property directly. There’s no point in using `const yOffset` here. `this.yOffset` is either `window.yOffset` or results in a TypeError. It has nothing to do with your `const yOffset;`.

Comment: `this.yOffset` refers to the `yOffset` _property_ of whatever `this` refers to at any given time. If you want to use a variable, just use the variable name, without `this`. And in order for that to work, `yOffset` would need to be outside of the `activeLink` function and be a `let`, not `const`. But as Sebastian points out, it seems like you don't really need a variable for this and can read the `pageYOffset` from the window directly.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks a lot! Using `window.pageYOffset` directly seems to work! When I use `let` and set my `yOffset` variable outside the `activeLink` function, it doesn't work though. Any idea why that might be?